# Removing double spaces from a char array

Tags: c++

Trying to write a program to clean up a string. However for some reason I'm having problem with double spaces. Either it only removes half of the excess spaces, or it just runs forever.

```
char input[246] = {'\0'};
    bool done = false;
    int count = 0;
    while (!done)
    {
        cout << "Hello, please enter a string to translate." << endl;
        cin.get(input, 246);
    }

for (int i = 0; i <= 246; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] != '\0')
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

for (int i = 0; i <= count - 1;)  //remove double spaces
    {
        while (input[i] == ' ' && input[i + 1] == ' ')
        {
            for (int q = i + 1; q <= (count - 1) - i; q++)
            {
                input[q] = input[q + 1];
            }
            count--;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= 246; i++)` is incorrect. Array indices start with `0`, and so must stop **1 before the size**. i.e. the condition must be `i < 246`.

Comment: Don't count the length of a null-terminated string yourself, use [`std::strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) instead. Or better yet, stop using C-style null-terminated strings and arrays, and use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: An easier approach might be two pointers, or two indices, that indicate the current read position and the current write position. Every time through the loop, copy from the read position to the write position. When you hit a double space, move the read position forward 2, and the write position forward only 1.

Comment: Saw a very similar question just a few hours ago https://stackoverflow.com/q/58405234/391691

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) with a custom predicate to remove duplicate spaces:

```
auto last = std::unique(&input[0], input + strlen(input), [](char const& a, char const &b)
{
    return std::isspace(a) && std::isspace(b);
});
*last = '\0';  // Terminate string
```

Comment: This made my program freeze? What would the custom predicate be?

Comment: @ErikWilder [Works very fine for me](https://ideone.com/3JxaHR). The predicate is the [*lambda expression*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) given as the last argument to `std::unique`.

Answer (score 0):

From your algorithm, it should be

```
while (input[i] == ' ' && input[i + 1] == ' ')
{
    for (int q = i + 1; q <= count - 1; q++) // Change that line
    {
        input[q] = input[q + 1];
    }
    count--;
}
else
{
    i++;
}
```

but alternative solution with `std::unique` is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. That worked, but I'm trying to replace it with the custom.